# PHP Operators Priority OR match

Tags: php

Today I had to handle a string match, and I wanted to do this:

```
if($somevalue == ( "would"||"be"||"cool" ) ) {...
```

Was in PHP 5.3, gave no errors, and felt right to me, maybe I've been programming to long in to many languages, and lost track of small things such as this lol.. so I went with it. But it keep on puking on the 3rd option, overwriting other values, and other odd stuff. In the end I went with:

```
if($somevalue == "would" || $somevalue == "be" || $somevalue == "cool") {...
```

Got the job done for work, and I went on my way. But, it keeps eating at me, because I feel the first if block should have worked.. Am I just getting off track?? What would be the correct way to write the block?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't work at all like you're trying to make it work, in PHP or in any other language:

```
if($somevalue == ( "would"||"be"||"cool" ) ) {...
```

The `(a || b || c)` gets evaluated *first*, and the result gets compared to `$somevalue`.

In your case, all three are constants and all three are truthy, so `( "would"||"be"||"cool" )` will *always* evaluate to `true`, and your if statement will always and only ever evaluate as

```
if($somevalue == true)
```

If you want to check if a variable is included in a set of strings, either use the second example you posted `(x == a || x == b || x == c)`, or try `in_array`:

```
$strings = array("would", "be", "cool");

if (in_array($somevalue, $strings)) {...
```

Comment: I was just about to post the `in_array` method, but you beat me to it. Another way, if you have several different groups of strings to compare with, is with `switch`.

Comment: Very true.. I've been hammering out complex queries for the last week. Brain getting scrambled lol. Think I was thinking something like HAVING/IN.. which is, as you both pointed out, in_array. Thanks guys!